# Can only connect to network after changing MAC

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, netplan

I have a machine running Ubuntu Server 22.04, It has been working fine for the past serveral days, however today I noticed it appeared down on my network.

I could not SSH to the machine so I accessed it manually via Keyboard/Monitor.

I tried rebooting the machine to see if it was a temporary issue, using a different Ethernet cable, forgetting the device in UniFi and using various different netplan configs, alongside checking with `netplan apply --debug`. However I could not get the machine to connect to my network. Every time I would yield Destination is unreachable & Could only ping the machines own IP that was listed under enp2s0 in `ip a`. Attempts to reinstall Ubuntu on the machine have yielded the same issue in which an IP with neither be fetched dynamically via DHCP nor via static settings. UFW is also disabled.

I have also verified it is not the Ethernet cable & the IP is not duplicate on another network device.

Upon changing the MAC for the machine however I can temporarily regain connectivity until the machine reboots. Naturally for failover sake I cannot manually change the MAC of the machine every time it goes down. It is also probably not worth "duct tape" fixing and ensuring that the command is run as a service on system boot or something, which seems a bit of a hacky fixy.

Has anyone experiences this before or have any idea how I can either make the MAC changes persistent across reboots or advise me on further troubleshooting / fixes?

It would seem to me that this could also be a network level issue given that it occurred at a random point in time & persists across system reinstalls. MAC Address filtering is also not enabled in the UniFi console.

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/920020/netplan-not-spoofing-mac-as-expected